# Does Gallium (liquid or solid) corrode all forms of brass?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metallurgy

I know that it corrodes copper, but does it do the same to all brass or bronze compositions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_metal)

> Gallium is corrosive to all metals except tungsten and tantalum, which have a high resistance to corrosion.

Beta-Brass is [embrittled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_metal_embrittlement) by [Gallium](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0956716X9090573Y)

Due to its highly reducing character it is highly corrosive material.

Comment: As I understand it, 316 stainless steel is fairly resistant as long as we are not talking structural use

Comment: I found it actually does corrode 316 steel [here](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/250011771_Corrosion_of_martensitic_and_austenitic_steels_in_liquid_gallium) , [here](http://corrosionjournal.org/doi/abs/10.5006/1.3287729). But [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1004359410957), the penetration seems to be only $12 \mu m$. I probably think under no stress conditions, 316 is resistant to Gallium due to passivation.

Answer (score 2):

I had looked at more direct sources from the Wikipedia link that was provided in the previous answer to this question. On page 99 of the 1954 version of "Liquid-Metals Handbook", there is a chart that might answer your question better:

[image: resistance of materials to attack by gallium]

The next two pages from the the same book gives more information about the other chemicals that leads me to believe that the Wikipedia article might be misquoting the information.

Comment: Please embed all the mentioned URLs (you can use standard `[text](link)` Markdown) as well as an *exact* and *complete* reference for the illustration, including author(s)/editor(s), publisher, page number(s) and IDs (ISBN/ISSN/DOI/…), preferably using ACS citation style. Currently it's quite hard to follow the timeline and to understand what quotes what in here. Also note that "Wikipedia" is capitalized.