# Gallium - Practical use to remove aluminium

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metal, crystal-structure

Would gallium pass through aluminium into steel?

The situation is two joined pieces of metal.

Gallium could be applied to the aluminium to degrade it, for mechanical removal, but would it pass through to attack the steel beneath or remain within the aluminium?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Gallium (liquid or solid) corrode all forms of brass?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27900/does-gallium-liquid-or-solid-corrode-all-forms-of-brass)

Comment: Not a duplicate of the brass corrosion thread, this is specifically about practical gallium/aluminium/steel interactions. Literature indicates that gallium will damage steel, but whether this is occurs much more slowly than in aluminium and whether the gallium would transfer out of the aluminium are unanswered.

Comment: Did you read the answer? "Gallium is corrosive to all metals except tungsten and tantalum, which have a high resistance to corrosion."

Comment: Hi MaxW, I did. Apologies if my questions are not well phrased, I think I see the confusion and will edit the question phrasing. The question is not whether gallium is corrosive, it is.

Comment: Think you're looking at this incorrectly. (1) I doubt that you could get the gallium only on the aluminum post. (2) When breaking apart the aluminum post you're going to get crud on the steel frame. // So what you propose isn't impossible, but what is the correct procedure to get it to work? Got some spare bikes to experiment with?

Comment: 1) Perhaps 2) This is another way of looking at the crux of the question.... By crud I assume you mean the bits of brittle aluminium infiltrated by gallium. Would this crud itself damage the steel, or is the gallium 'happy' to stay within the aluminium doing no harm?